# Writing a COM Interop Assembly for a .NET assembly to be consumed by a VB6 app

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com-interop

I'm trying to create a COM Interop assembly (myComInterop.dll) between my vb6 app and a .net assembly.  I'm also trying to make it so that it can be "registration free" ([see here for explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/genman32-a-tool-to-generate-sxs-manifest-for-managed-assembly-for-registration-free-com-net-interop)).  The freedom from registration requires that I create a MyVb6App.exe.manifest file, and also that I use a strong name to sign myComInterop.dll.  However, the references in myComInterop.dll require the dependent assemblies to be signed with a strong name, as well.  The problem is that some of the dependent assemblies are 3rd party libraries that we can't rebuild them as delay signed or sign them ourselves.

Is there a way to get around this requirement that the dependent dlls be signed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think it needs be strong named?  This is not a requirement for reg-free COM, nor does the example given in the blog post use a strong-named assembly.

Comment: Maybe I'm missunderstanding reg-free COM.  What are the main requirements?

Comment: Just a properly formatted manifest.  And having the files in the right place.  It won't work when you debug from the VB6 IDE.